# Qt 5.12: Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm"

Tags: qt, opengl, cmake, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

I have a freshly installed `Ubuntu 18.04.3` system (NVIDIA) with only `Qt SDK 5.12.5`, `build-essential`, `git`, and `CMake` installed. I'm trying to build a Qt project by opening the main CMakeLists.txt in Qt Creator:

```
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /home/juzzlin/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:9 (message):
  Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/juzzlin/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:174 (include)
  /home/juzzlin/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:89 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:89 (find_package)
```

What should I still install?

Note: I haven't installed Qt from repositories at all. Only via the official online installer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need `mesa` packages.

- mesa-common-dev
- libglu1-mesa-dev

`$ sudo apt install mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`
And Try.

Comment: Worked for me. Is this documented anywhere?... The Qt documentation/support should mention it...

Comment: @Wouzz,  `mesa` packages is a open-source implementation of the OpenGL specification and needed for OpenGL applications.

Answer (score 15):

If anybody using Fedora/RHEL finds this question, `mesa` packages are named differently here.

- mesa-libGL
- mesa-libGL-devel

`$ sudo dnf install mesa-libGL mesa-libGL-devel`

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/56301

Answer (score 6):

In OpenSuse Leap `mesa` packages are named differently too.

Use:

```
sudo zypper install Mesa-libGL-devel
```

to solve it.
I tried it with OpenSuse Leap 15.2 and 15.3.

Answer (score 0):

For centos 7

```bash
sudo yum install libGL-devel
```